# Trying to use token acquisition with ADFS authenticated app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, powerbi-embedded, microsoft-identity-platform

I am stuck on a problem that i cannot think my way out of and have searched everywhere online for answers to no avail.
Here is the problem:
I usually embed PowerBI reports in asp.net application. I follow the Microsoft tutorial. Where we registered an azureAD app as service principal. And we use the Microsoft.Identity.Web library to authenticate our users as well as authenticate as the app's service principal for accessing PowerBI reports.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(PowerBiServiceApi));
```

The problem now is that I am building an app that doesn’t authenticate with the Microsoft.Identity.Web but will actually be authenticating users using individual accounts/ ADFS and federation service.

The problem is that I am unable to do token acquisition by authenticating as the app's service principal.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
         {
             options.ClientId = "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx";
             options.Authority = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx";
             options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:xxxx/";
             options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
             {
                 OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,
             };

         })

.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

However when I am unable to run this app and embed successfully.
My main question is:
is it possible to authenticate my users with one authentication provider (ADFS federation service via openID or wsFederation )
whilst also doing using Microsoft.Identity to do token acquisition

Answer (score 0):

Thus far I've had success with using OpenIDConnect directly with ADFS and MSAL library to get tokens (also from ADFS) for downstream api's.  For entries in ADFS using a client secret (i.e. server apps) I would use the `IConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder`, whereas native apps would use `IPublicClientApplicaationBuilder`.

This means I never need nor can use this code:
`.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")) .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`